# Disable a link for some time or during animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I would like to disable a link during animation, I animate using backgroundPosition and when I click while the first animation is still on, it breaks the background. so to prevent that I have two questions actually:

How to disable 'click' event on link while the element is animating (animation always lasts 4000, so it could be either while the animation is on, or by set amount of time)

```
$("#arrows a").on("click", function () {  

var newPos = ....   

        $("#bg").stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: newPos
        }, 4000) 
});
```

And the next question is: how to actually determine if element is animated and when is not? Does it have to be stopped somehow to actually be set as on and off? I tried various options, nothing works, when I tried this code then it always displays class 'animated' - so it means it  never stops until next click?

```
if ($("#bg").is(":animated") ) {
            $("#game").addClass("animated");
} else {
            $("#game").addClass("stopped");
}
```

If I could find solution how to add those classes, it would solve the first issue with the link, cause I could then simply remove the links with css

UPDATE:
After 'caramba' comment with tip what to look for I moved further, animate complete was the answer, before that I was googling for couple of hours and had never stumbled upon this. Anyway, this is my code now:

```
 $("#bg").stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: newPos
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 4000,
            complete: function() {
                console.log("ok");
                $("#game").addClass("completed")
                // setTimeout(function() {
                    // $("#arrows a").unbind();
                // }, 4000);
           }
       });
```

It adds the class nicely, but I was also trying to fit there setTimeout to disable the link for the time animation lasts, but it disabled it complete, where is the problem?

*PS. How do I vote the comments? I can't see any options to add votes, and I would like to thank for the comment, is it not available for newbies, or am I just blind?*

Comment: search for "jquery animate complete" and or "jquery queue"

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question with further step. Still can't figure out how to disable the link with jquery when animation is on. 'return false' doesn't work as it is for href only, which I already disabled, so I'm trying to unbind the click, but how to put it back after those 4000ms?

Comment: If possible, can post included `html`, `css`, `js` ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to me it is not real clear what you are trying to do but I've set up two examples. 
(For the next time you ask a question if would be very helpful is you share your HTML markup for everyone here and yourself)

Anyway, two examples:

1. jQuery - animation - complete
2. jQuery - queue

**1. jQuery - animation - complete**
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5c4G/1/)

This is i think the simplest way to check when the animation is finished, all you need to do is write your animation function like this:

lets say this is your markup cause you didn't show any:

```
<div id="arrows">
    <a href="http://www.google.com?click1" target="_blank">click 1</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com?click2" target="_blank">click 2</a>
    <a href="http.//www.google.com?click3" target="_blank">click 3</a>
<div>

<div id="bg"></div>
```

and this is your javascript:

```
$("#arrows a").on("click", function (e) {  
        e.preventDefault(); // don't let the link do hes work
        var link = $(this).attr("href"); //get the href
        var newPos = '300'; // set newPos 
        $("#bg").animate({  //start animation
            left: "+="+newPos+'px' //animate till here
        }, 2000, function(){
            //the animation is finished
            alert("animation finished");
            // what would you like to do here?
            // maybe need the link
            alert(link);
        });
});
```

**2. jQuery - queue** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5c4G/3/)

```
<p class="showQueue">0</p>
<p class="animating">Waiting for animation</p>
<p class="globalAnimationVar">GlobalAnimationVar</p>
<div id="arrows">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">click 1</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">click 2</a>
    <a href="http.//www.google.com">click 3</a>
<div>

<div id="bg"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var globalCheckAnimation=false;
showQueue(); // call the showQueue function
function showQueue() {
    var queue = $("#bg").queue("fx"); //check if the element is animating
    if(queue.length > 0) { // do some stuff if it is animating
        $('.animating').text('YES we are animating');
        globalCheckAnimation=true;
        $('.globalAnimationVar').text(globalCheckAnimation);
    } else {
        $('.animating').text('Waiting for animation');
        globalCheckAnimation=false;
        $('.globalAnimationVar').text(globalCheckAnimation);
    }
    $( ".showQueue" ).text( queue.length ); // which "size/amount" from animation
    setTimeout( showQueue, 100 ); // repeat the function every 100 milli secconds
}

$("#arrows a").on("click", function (e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        var newPos = '300'; 
        $("#bg").animate({
            left: "+="+newPos+'px'
        }, 2000, function(){
            //here the animation is finished
            //we could use the globalCheckAnimation var
            //alert(globalCheckAnimation);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for spending so much time on this detailed reply. Your way of checking if animation is 'on' is very helpful. However I still have problem with preventing links to queue aniamtions if existing animation is still on. I am already using e.preventDefault() , but if I click on arrow - until that animation is finished I want the arrow to be completely inactive, so double or triple clicking is prevented.

Comment: In your examples aniamtions build up, on my background goes to 50% when arrow is double clicked, I thought that maybe it would be better to prevent double clicking? My code: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/kXQ99/18/

Comment: @yennefer many ways go to Rome :-) have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/kXQ99/19/ now after click we add a class to the element (dontLetMeClick) and disable the clickability with css when animation is finished we remove the class again.

Comment: cool :) and simple.  pointer-events: none; works in IE 11+ though, that's why I was looking for js solution, although I'm so confused now, as e.preventDefault() and return false work on default href functionality, not the click event :(

Comment: that's right. e.preventDefault works on href but your click function triggers on the <div id="arrows"> which is the parent from the <a>.. try like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kXQ99/21/